# wxPython EVT_CHAR not called when a panel is added to a frame

Tags: python, wxpython

I need to bind the EVT_CHAR event for a GUI application I am developing using wxPython. I tried the following and I cann understand the beahviour of the code.

```
import wx
import wx.lib.agw.flatnotebook as fnb

class DemoApp(wx.App):

    def __init__(self):
        wx.App.__init__(self, redirect=False)

        self.mainFrame = DemoFrame()
        self.mainFrame.Show()

    def OnInit(self):
        return True


class DemoFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY,
                          "FlatNotebook Tutorial",
                          size=(600,400)
                          )
        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        button = wx.Button(panel, label="Close", pos=(125, 10), size=(50, 50))

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CHAR, self.character)

    def character(self, event):  
        print "Char keycode : {0}".format(event.GetKeyCode())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = DemoApp()
    app.MainLoop()
```

The character function never gets called. However, when I comment out the two lines call to the Frame constructor, I character function is called. Adding a panel to the frame seems to interfere with the binding of the frame's EVT_CHAR.

How do I address this problem? Am I doing something wrong in my code?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you are catching events that happen to the frame, but the frame is not in focus. The button is. In wxPython, events are sent to the widget in focus. If you add this to the end of your **init**, it works:

```
self.SetFocus()
```

However, if you change the focus to the button, then it will stop working again. See also:

- [wxpython capture keyboard events in a wx.Frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8707160/wxpython-capture-keyboard-events-in-a-wx-frame)
- http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2009/08/29/wxpython-catching-key-and-char-events/
- http://wxpython-users.1045709.n5.nabble.com/Catching-key-events-from-a-panel-and-follow-up-to-stacked-panels-td2360109.html

Answer (score 2):

I appreciate that this question was answered 2 years ago but this issue catches us all out at some point or other.
It is the classic binding to wx.Event or wx.CommandEvent problem.
In this case simply changing the `self.Bind(wx.EVT_CHAR, self.character)` line to read `button.Bind(wx.EVT_CHAR, self.character)` will solve the problem, detailed above.
The issue of wx.Event - wx.CommandEvent is covered in full here:
http://wiki.wxpython.org/EventPropagation
and here:
http://wiki.wxpython.org/self.Bind%20vs.%20self.button.Bind